# asp:DropDownList - possible to have submenu?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, submenu

I'm using the asp.net dropdownlist which is populated from a database. Is it possible to have sub menus on any of the options in the list? Or how could this normally be done?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's exactly possible using the DropDownList.  It can be done using the asp.net menu control though:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Could just add a type of prefix to specify a sub item like so:

```
<select>
    <option>Top</option>
    <option> - Sub Topic</option>
</select>
```

You might be better off using nested lists that are [CSS styled properly](http://www.seoconsultants.com/css/menus/tutorial/)

```
<ul>
    <li>Topic
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Topic</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```